# How do you label only the odd or even integers of a field using python in the label expression in arcmap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, labeling, python-parser, expression

I'm new to python and would like to use the label expression box with python to display only the odd or even integers from the field, [Frame_Number].

I was thinking something like

```
def FindLabel ( [Frame_Number] ):
  for num in [Frame_Number]:
     return num % 2
  return [Frame_Number]
```

But I know that is incomplete.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Label expressions are similar to field calculator: you don't need to use a `for` loop as the expression is already applied to every feature. Also, you'll get an error with your code as per the [help](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/map/working-with-text/about-building-label-expressions.htm):

> **Field values are automatically cast to text strings**. Therefore, if you
>   wish to use a numeric value in an arithmetic operation, or when making
>   a comparison, you will need to cast it back to a numeric data type.
>   The examples below add two integer fields

Here it is displaying odd values:

```py
def FindLabel([Frame_Number]):
  return [Frame_Number] if int([Frame_Number]) % 2 else "whatever you want here"
```

Alternatively, you can use a SQL expression in [Label Manager](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/map/working-with-text/displaying-labels-using-label-classes-to-label-fea.htm) to accomplish the same:

`MOD(Frame_Number, 2) = 1`